# Adding line break in a PDF with XSL-FO?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Trying to create a PDF file based on an XML and a  file using XMLSpy.

I'm trying to split a field into two lines based on the field content.

For example, if my varialbe = "John Doe AKA Johnny D", I want to view it like this :

John Doe

Johnny D

My problem is that I can't make it work even with all the samples on the net.

Here's my code :

```
     <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat(substring-before(//MyField,'AKA'),$newline,substring-after(//MyField,'AKA'))" /> 
  </xsl:when>
```

So basically, eveytime I find the "AKA" string, I want to break the field into two lines.
So my code, finds the string, create the new variable but still shows in one line. 
I've tried creating a variable with a blank line, using all kinds of techiniques but still shows in one line.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661483/inserting-a-line-break-in-a-pdf-generated-from-xsl-fo-using-xslvalue-of/3664468#3664468) about using a hex entity reference and `linefeed-treatment`.

---

**Edit**

I took your code from the comments and put it in template in a sample XSLT stylesheet. The only thing I changed was:

1. I changed your `newline` variable to `&#xA;`.
2. I added `linefeed-treatment="preserve"` to your `fo:block`.

Using a dummy XML file and the XSLT stylesheet, I produced an XSL-FO document that when rendered with FOP, produces "John Doe" and "Johnny D" on separate lines.

Here is the XML file:

```
<doc>
  <MyField>John Doe AKA Johnny D</MyField>
</doc>
```

Here is the XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
          <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc">
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xA;'"/>        
    <xsl:variable name="MyVar">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(//MyField,'AKA')">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(//MyField,'AKA'),$newline,substring-after(//MyField,'AKA'))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="//MyField"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
      <xsl:value-of select="$MyVar"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the resulting XSL-FO:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
         <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
               <fo:simple-page-master page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" master-name="my-page">
                  <fo:region-body margin-top="1.5in" margin="1in"/>
               </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
               <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                  <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">John Doe 
 Johnny D</fo:block>
               </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
         </fo:root>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

The PDF is a single 8.5" x 11" page with this on it:

```
John Doe
Johnny D
```

Comment: It's just not working for me. I have used many samples found here but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your link didn't come through. Also, are you using Apache FOP for your processor?

Comment: Sorry, when I said, found here, I mean in this forum. ...and yes, I am using Apache FOP.

Comment: Can you post more of your code so that I/we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Here it is. Thanks in advance for all te attention.

<xsl:variable name="newline"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

   
<xsl:variable name="MyVar">

 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains(//MyField,'AKA')">

   <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(//MyField,'AKA'),$newline,substring-after(//MyField,'AKA'))" />
        
  

  </xsl:when>        
      
  <xsl:otherwise> 
   <xsl:value-of select="//MyField" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
 
 </xsl:choose>
 
</xsl:variable>


<fo:block><xsl:value-of select="$MyVar"/></fo:block>

Comment: It's working now. Thanks so much. I was adding the  linefeed-treatment="preserve" in the wrong place. Works like a charm now. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I know this is an older post, but holy crap it just saved me after an hour of searching :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @daniel-haley still produces a single pair of names when the source is:

```
<doc>
    <MyField>John Doe AKA Johnny D</MyField>
    <MyField>Johnny D AKA John Doe</MyField>
    <MyField>John Smith</MyField>
</doc>
```

(In XPath 1.0, converting a node-set to a string returns the string value of only the node in the node-set that is first in document order.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string.)

The stylesheet below splits any text node containing "`AKA`".  Since the enclosing `fo:block` comes from the `xsl:template` for `MyField`, this version generates an empty `fo:block` to cause the line break.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
                <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Could change to match on 'MyField/text()[contains(., ' AKA ')]'
     if necessary. -->
<xsl:template match="text()[contains(., ' AKA ')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' AKA ')" />
    <fo:block />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ' AKA ')" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MyField">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```