# Retain the &#xA; during xml marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, xsl-fo

I am generating the xml by marshalling the xsd and I have xsl-fo to generate the pdf. I have a description field which has to be broken down to new lines.Something similar to what is in this thread [Inserting a line break in a PDF generated from XSL FO using <xsl:value-of>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661483/inserting-a-line-break-in-a-pdf-generated-from-xsl-fo-using-xslvalue-of)

This is my code to marshall

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(List.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.FALSE);
            m.marshal(OrderList, stream);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            m.marshal(OrderList, sw);
            String val = sw.toString();
            System.out.println(val);
```

When I marshall, generated xml doesn't retain `&#xA;` instead it adds `&amp;#xA;` and the result is something like this
`<description>REPAIR CAB DOOR&amp;#xA;REPAIR &amp;#xA;</description>`. If I don't have `&#xA` in the xml I can't create a line break in my pdf.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289036/how-to-prevent-jaxb-escaping-a-string Maybe a new character escape handler will help.

Comment: @DevNull I tried the CharacterEscapeHandler example and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I' guessing here (albeit somewhat educated). Whatever your input is to the generation  of the `<description>` element, it should not contain `&#xA`, but rather just `'\n'`. I.e., instead of:

```
"This is a List:&#xA;List item 1&#xA;List item 2&#xA;List item 3&#xA;List item 4"
```

it shoudl be

```
"This is a List:\nList item 1\nList item 2\nList item 3\nList item 4"
```

Comment: `\n` did the trick. Many examples have given `&#xA;` should be what we have to use and add `linefeed-treatment="preserve"` to <fo:block> to create the line break.